# data.table replicate rows after join?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I'm not sure I'm facing this right, so first I'll try to show the problem I'm trying to solve and then the way I'm trying to do so. Feel free to tell me how wrong I am, and any better approach you can think of.

I have three data.tables (the actual "input" one is way bigger and performance matters, so I have to use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) as much as I can):

**Input:**

```
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
|   ID   | T1 | T2 | T3 |    DATE    | 
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  0 | 31/12/2016 |
| ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  1 | 30/06/2017 |
| ACC002 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 31/12/2016 |
| ACC002 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 30/06/2017 |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
```

**mevs:**

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|    DATE    | INDEX_NAME | INDEX_VALUE |
+------------+------------+-------------+
| 31/12/2016 | GDP        |  1.05       |
| 30/06/2017 | GDP        |  1.06       |
| 31/12/2017 | GDP        |  1.07       |
| 30/06/2018 | GDP        |  1.08       |
| 31/12/2016 | CPI        |  0.02       |
| 30/06/2017 | CPI        |  0.00       |
| 31/12/2017 | CPI        | -0.01       |
| 30/06/2018 | CPI        |  0.01       |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

**time:**

```
+------------+
|    DATE    |
+------------+
| 31/12/2016 |
| 30/06/2017 |
| 31/12/2017 |
| 30/06/2018 |
+------------+
```

With those, I need to achieve 2 things:

- Insert GDP and CPI values from the second dt(mevs) into the first one (input), to make some calculations in the last column based on T1, T2, T3, GDP and CPI.
- Make a projection for the time intervals given in the third dt (time), copying T1, T2 and T3 values in the previous interval in the same ID (so ACC001 ones would remain (1, 0, 1)) and getting GDP and CPI from the corresponding dates. The final calculation would be done using the same function.

Which should result in an "input" dt like this:

```
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+-------+------+
| ID     | T1 | T2 | T3 | DATE       | GDP  | CPI   | CALC |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+-------+------+
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 31/12/2016 | 1.05 | 0.02  | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 30/06/2017 | 1.06 | 0.00  | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 31/12/2017 | 1.07 | -0.01 | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 30/06/2018 | 1.08 | 0.01  | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 31/12/2016 | 1.05 | 0.02  | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 30/06/2017 | 1.06 | 0.00  | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 31/12/2017 | 1.07 | -0.01 | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 30/06/2018 | 1.08 | 0.01  | fun  |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+-------+------+
```

What I've managed to do:

- `mevs <- mevs %>% tidyr::spread(INDEX_NAME, INDEX_VALUE)` to get indexes values into columns.
- `input[mevs, ':=' (GDP = i.GDP, CPI = i.CPI), on = "RUN_DATE"]` to set indexes values (avoiding assignations, if I'm not mistaken).

Resulting in:

```
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+------+------+
| ID     | C1 | C2 | C3 | DATE       | GDP  | CPI  | CALC |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+------+------+
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 31/12/2016 | 1.05 | 0.02 | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 30/06/2017 | 1.06 | 0    | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 31/12/2016 | 1.05 | 0.02 | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 30/06/2017 | 1.06 | 0    | fun  |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+------+------+
```

What I'm don't know how to do properly:

I'm trying to do a right outer join (before the "selective join" on the second step at "What I'm doing") with "input"-"time" based on "DATE" with the following code: `input <- input[time, on = "DATE"]`. But not only it doesn't work properly (I get NAs in the ID column, which I needed for the next step), it also forces me to make an assignment.

After that, I was planning on doing another join with "input"-"input" based on "ID", but obviously I can't since I don't have any ID value in those new rows:

```
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| ID     | T1 | T2 | T3 | DATE       |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 31/12/2016 |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 30/06/2017 |
| NA     | NA | NA | NA | 31/12/2017 |
| NA     | NA | NA | NA | 30/06/2018 |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 31/12/2016 |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 30/06/2017 |
| NA     | NA | NA | NA | 31/12/2017 |
| NA     | NA | NA | NA | 30/06/2018 |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
```

Is there any way to, for example, replicate those IDs based on some condition on the DATE column? If not, do you know any other solution, maybe based on `rbindlist`?

Thanks so much for making this far. Any advice will be highly appreciated!

#### Extra questions

**Avoiding assignment**

@Jaap 's solution returns the desired data.table, thanks to that. I'd need to turn input into that last data.table, without using the standard assigment (`<-`) unless unavoidable. How can this be done in this case?

**Conditionals**

I'd need to introduce a particularity to the last part of the scrip. If there's an ID without some registries before the projections, T1/T2/T3 have to be 0 in the projections. That would be the case of ACC002 here, which doesn't have registries beyond 31/12/2016:

```
input <- fread("  ID   | T1 | T2 | T3 |    DATE    
                ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  0 | 31/12/2016 
                ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  1 | 30/06/2017 
                ACC002 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 31/12/2016", sep = "|")
```

That should finally become:

```
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+-------+------+
| ID     | T1 | T2 | T3 | DATE       | GDP  | CPI   | CALC |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+-------+------+
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 31/12/2016 | 1.05 | 0.02  | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 30/06/2017 | 1.06 | 0.00  | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 31/12/2017 | 1.07 | -0.01 | fun  |
| ACC001 | 1  | 0  | 1  | 30/06/2018 | 1.08 | 0.01  | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 1  | 1  | 31/12/2016 | 1.05 | 0.02  | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 30/06/2017 | 1.06 | 0.00  | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 31/12/2017 | 1.07 | -0.01 | fun  |
| ACC002 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 30/06/2018 | 1.08 | 0.01  | fun  |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+------+-------+------+
```

The actual finality of that is that the CALC column, which relies on a T1/T2/T3 dependant polynomial, is equal to 0 in that situation (in case you find it better to approach directly from there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
input[, .SD[time, on = "DATE"], by = ID
      ][dcast(mevs, DATE ~ INDEX_NAME), on = "DATE", `:=` (GDP = i.GDP, CPI = i.CPI)
        ][, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, zoo::na.locf), by = ID, .SDcols = 2:4][]
```

gives:

> ```
>        ID T1 T2 T3       DATE  GDP   CPI
> 1: ACC001  1  0  0 31/12/2016 1.05  0.02
> 2: ACC001  1  0  1 30/06/2017 1.06  0.00
> 3: ACC001  1  0  1 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
> 4: ACC001  1  0  1 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
> 5: ACC002  0  1  1 31/12/2016 1.05  0.02
> 6: ACC002  0  1  1 30/06/2017 1.06  0.00
> 7: ACC002  0  1  1 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
> 8: ACC002  0  1  1 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
> ```

What this does:

- `input[, .SD[time, on = "DATE"], by = ID]` joins for each `ID` the `time` data.table to the remaining columns, thus extending the data.table.
- A wide version of `mevs` (`dcast(mevs, DATE ~ INDEX_NAME)`) is then joined to the extended data.table.
- Finally the missing values in the extended data.table are filled with the `na.locf`-function from the [zoo](/questions/tagged/zoo) package.

---

To meet the extra condition of the updated question, you could do:

```
ones <- input[, .N, by = ID][N == 1, ID]

input[, .SD[time, on = "DATE"], by = ID
      ][dcast(mevs, DATE ~ INDEX_NAME), on = "DATE", `:=` (GDP = i.GDP, CPI = i.CPI)
        ][, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if (.BY %in% ones) replace(x, is.na(x), 0L) else zoo::na.locf(x) )
          , by = ID, .SDcols = 2:4][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>        ID T1 T2 T3       DATE  GDP   CPI
> 1: ACC001  1  0  0 31/12/2016 1.05  0.02
> 2: ACC001  1  0  1 30/06/2017 1.06  0.00
> 3: ACC001  1  0  1 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
> 4: ACC001  1  0  1 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
> 5: ACC002  0  1  1 31/12/2016 1.05  0.02
> 6: ACC002  0  0  0 30/06/2017 1.06  0.00
> 7: ACC002  0  0  0 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
> 8: ACC002  0  0  0 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
> ```

---

Used data:

```
input <- fread("  ID   | T1 | T2 | T3 |    DATE    
                ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  0 | 31/12/2016 
                ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  1 | 30/06/2017 
                ACC002 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 31/12/2016 
                ACC002 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 30/06/2017 ", sep = "|")

mevs <- fread("  DATE    | INDEX_NAME | INDEX_VALUE 
              31/12/2016 | GDP        |  1.05       
              30/06/2017 | GDP        |  1.06       
              31/12/2017 | GDP        |  1.07       
              30/06/2018 | GDP        |  1.08       
              31/12/2016 | CPI        |  0.02       
              30/06/2017 | CPI        |  0.00       
              31/12/2017 | CPI        | -0.01       
              30/06/2018 | CPI        |  0.01   ", sep = "|")

time <- fread("    DATE   
               31/12/2016 
               30/06/2017 
               31/12/2017 
               30/06/2018 ", sep = "|")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jaap. That piece of code is impressively neat! 

I didn't know zoo package either, it seems pretty useful.

I have a pair of aditional questions that I hope you can adress. I've edited my original post with them. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: @sneaky_lobster The assignment is unavoidable because you are extending the number of rows. Will look at the additional question in a minute.

Comment: @sneaky_lobster see the update with a possible solution for the additional requirement, HTH

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much! I wasn't sure how to implement IF there.

Comment: Just a doubt about the last piece of code, @Jaap. In that if (.BY %in% ones) part, what should be "ones"?

Comment: @sneaky_lobster I apparently forgot to include that in my answer. See the update.

Comment: Hello again, @Jaap. I found an unforeseen complication. Sometimes my "times" dt doesn't come with every date registred on "input". I don't exactly know why, but in those cases C1, C2 and C3 get filled with NAs (even those which share dates with "time", I don't understand that). I think it's mostly a problem of joins, but I can't find a workaround.

Comment: @sneaky_lobster Instead of updating your question every time, you should post the new problem as a new question and link back to this question. Let me know hen you've done so. Make sure to include all the necessary details (including the desired output).

Comment: my bad. Reading the rules, as it was related with the original, I thought it was the right thing to do. I'll do so, thanks.

Comment: Here you are, @Jaap. Thanks for your time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170892/selecting-correct-join-with-r-data-table