# Selecting correct join with data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table, na

A follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51087287/2204410).

I have three data tables (the actual `input` one is way bigger and performance matters, so I have to use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) as much as I can):

```
input <- fread("  ID   | T1 | T2 | T3 |    DATE    
                ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  0 | 31/12/2016 
                ACC001 |  1 |  0 |  1 | 30/06/2017 
                ACC002 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 31/12/2016", sep = "|")

mevs <- fread("  DATE    | INDEX_NAME | INDEX_VALUE 
              31/12/2016 | GDP        |  1.05       
              30/06/2017 | GDP        |  1.06       
              31/12/2017 | GDP        |  1.07       
              30/06/2018 | GDP        |  1.08       
              31/12/2016 | CPI        |  0.02       
              30/06/2017 | CPI        |  0.00       
              31/12/2017 | CPI        | -0.01       
              30/06/2018 | CPI        |  0.01   ", sep = "|")

time <- fread("    DATE   
               31/12/2017 
               30/06/2018 ", sep = "|")
```

With those, I need to achieve 2 things:

- Insert `GDP` and `CPI` values from the second dt(`mevs`) into the first one (`input`), to make some calculations in the last column based on `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `GDP` and `CPI`.
- Make a projection for the time intervals given in the third dt (`time`), copying `T1`, `T2` and `T3` values in the previous interval in the same `ID` (so ACC001 ones would remain `1, 0, 1`) if it exists (filling them with `0` if it doesn't) and getting `GDP` and `CPI` from the corresponding dates.

For that, I'm using the following pieces of code:

```
ones <- input[, .N, by = ID][N == 1, ID]

input[, .SD[time, on = "DATE"], by = ID
      ][dcast(mevs, DATE ~ INDEX_NAME), on = "DATE", `:=` (GDP = i.GDP, CPI = i.CPI)
        ][, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if (.BY %in% ones) replace(x, is.na(x), 0L) else zoo::na.locf(x) )
          , by = ID, .SDcols = 2:4][]
```

Which does (thanks to @Jaap):

- `input[, .SD[time, on = "DATE"], by = ID]` joins for each ID the time data.table to the remaining columns, thus extending the data.table.
- A wide version of mevs `(dcast(mevs, DATE ~ INDEX_NAME))` is then joined to the extended data.table.
- Finally the missing values in the extended data.table are filled with the `na.locf`-function from the `zoo` package.

The intended output would be:

```
       ID T1 T2 T3       DATE  GDP   CPI
1: ACC001  1  0  0 31/12/2016 1.05  0.02
2: ACC001  1  0  1 30/06/2017 1.06  0.00
3: ACC001  1  0  1 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
4: ACC001  1  0  1 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
5: ACC002  0  1  1 31/12/2016 1.05  0.02
6: ACC002  0  0  0 30/06/2017 1.06  0.00
7: ACC002  0  0  0 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
8: ACC002  0  0  0 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
```

But instead what I get is:

```
       ID T1 T2 T3       DATE  GDP   CPI
1: ACC001 NA NA NA 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
2: ACC001 NA NA NA 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
3: ACC002 NA NA NA 31/12/2017 1.07 -0.01
4: ACC002 NA NA NA 30/06/2018 1.08  0.01
```

I'm almost sure that it has to be a wrong join choice between `input` and `time` in the first step, but I can't find a workaround for this.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
times <- unique(rbindlist(list(time, as.data.table(unique(input$DATE))))
                )[, DATE := as.Date(DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")][order(DATE)]
input[, DATE := as.Date(DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")]
mevs[, DATE := as.Date(DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")]

ones <- input[, .N, by = ID][N == 1, ID]

input[, .SD[times, on = "DATE"], by = ID
      ][dcast(mevs, DATE ~ INDEX_NAME), on = "DATE", `:=` (GDP = i.GDP, CPI = i.CPI)
        ][, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if (.BY %in% ones) replace(x, is.na(x), 0L) else zoo::na.locf(x) )
          , by = ID, .SDcols = 2:4][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>        ID T1 T2 T3       DATE  GDP   CPI
> 1: ACC001  1  0  0 2016-12-31 1.05  0.02
> 2: ACC001  1  0  1 2017-06-30 1.06  0.00
> 3: ACC001  1  0  1 2017-12-31 1.07 -0.01
> 4: ACC001  1  0  1 2018-06-30 1.08  0.01
> 5: ACC002  0  1  1 2016-12-31 1.05  0.02
> 6: ACC002  0  0  0 2017-06-30 1.06  0.00
> 7: ACC002  0  0  0 2017-12-31 1.07 -0.01
> 8: ACC002  0  0  0 2018-06-30 1.08  0.01
> ```